# How to build just Qt core libraries from Qt sources

Tags: qt, cmake, qt6

I'm trying to build minimalistic version of QT 6.x.x for my QtJambi project.
Just a QT library for the basic QT classes, QApplication, QMessageBox, QTreeView, QFileIconProvider and all the usual QT widgets.
Qt: 6.6.2
OS: Linux

I assume, all I need is to build `libQt6Core.so` and for that I need to build just `qtbase`.

The `configure --help` doesn't help much.

What is the option for `configure` to build just `qtbase` module?
Is `qtbase` even a module?

Since Qt 6, project changed build system to CMake.
Unfortunately, because of that, many of the help advices you can find on internet are not valid any more, like this one:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/71651/how-to-compile-only-a-minimum-set-of-modules

Background: QT6 provided by openSuse is not compatible with QtJambi;
getting errors like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/QtJambi6.6.2_4775/lib/libQtJambi.so.6.6.2: /usr/lib64/libQt6Core.so.6.6.2: version `Qt_6_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /tmp/QtJambi6.6.2_4775/lib/libQtJambi.so.6.6.2)
```

**UPDATE**
In this post, official from QT, https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-6-build-system, they show how to skip building of specified modules:

```
configure -skip qtsvg
```

Good to know, but how specify rather what I want to build, the *white list* approach?

**UPDATE**
I'm a Java developer. Building C based libraries goes a bit beyond my usual experience. Please bear with me; be as explicit as possible.

Comment: If you want to build only QtBase then call configure inside QtBase directly.